# Add progress bar in JavaFX table pagination

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have this example of JavaFX table.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Pagination;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application
{

    private final static int dataSize = 10_023;
    private final static int rowsPerPage = 1000;

    private final TableView<Sample> table = createTable();
    private final List<Sample> data = createData();

    private List<Sample> createData()
    {
        List<Sample> data = new ArrayList<>(dataSize);

        for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
        {
            data.add(new Sample(i, "foo " + i, "bar " + i));
        }

        return data;
    }

    private TableView<Sample> createTable()
    {

        TableView<Sample> table = new TableView<>();

        TableColumn<Sample, Integer> column1 = new TableColumn<>("Id");
        column1.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().id);
        column1.setPrefWidth(150);

        TableColumn<Sample, String> column2 = new TableColumn<>("Foo");
        column2.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().foo);
        column2.setPrefWidth(250);

        TableColumn<Sample, String> column3 = new TableColumn<>("Bar");
        column3.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().bar);
        column3.setPrefWidth(250);

        table.getColumns().addAll(column1, column2, column3);

        return table;
    }

    private Node createPage(int pageIndex)
    {

        int fromIndex = pageIndex * rowsPerPage;
        int toIndex = Math.min(fromIndex + rowsPerPage, data.size());
        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)));

        return new BorderPane(table);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception
    {

        Pagination pagination = new Pagination((data.size() / rowsPerPage + 1), 0);
        pagination.setPageFactory(this::createPage);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(pagination), 1024, 768);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Table pager");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class Sample
    {

        private final ObservableValue<Integer> id;
        private final SimpleStringProperty foo;
        private final SimpleStringProperty bar;

        private Sample(int id, String foo, String bar)
        {
            this.id = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(id);
            this.foo = new SimpleStringProperty(foo);
            this.bar = new SimpleStringProperty(bar);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to add Progress bar when pages are switched and data is loaded?

It's not very clear how I can use progress indicator while data is loaded.

Is there any useful example?

Comment: its unclear (to me, at least) what exactly you are asking...

Comment: Please post some code that is relevant to the question (i.e. the data should take some time to load, and should be loaded in the background) and show what you have tried. The code you posted bears very little resemblance to the problem you describe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution would be to rewrite the `createPage(int)` method:

1. Replace the [placeholder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#placeholderProperty) of the `TableView` with a [`ProgressIndicator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ProgressIndicator.html).
2. Create a [`Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) that computes the contents of the next page (in my example just a dummy doing `Thread.sleep()`).
3. When the `Task` is done replace the placeholder with the old one (backup & restore) and set the data to the `TableView`.

This is a small working example of the `createPage()` method:

```
private Node createPage(int pageIndex) {
    Node oldPlaceHolder = table.getPlaceholder();

    ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator();
    progress.setMaxSize(90, 90);
    table.setPlaceholder(new StackPane(progress));
    table.getItems().clear();

    Task<ObservableList<Sample>> task = new Task<ObservableList<Sample>>() {

        @Override
        protected ObservableList<Sample> call() throws Exception {
            for(int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
            {
                Thread.sleep(20);
                updateProgress(i, 100);
            }
            int fromIndex = pageIndex * rowsPerPage;
            int toIndex = Math.min(fromIndex + rowsPerPage, data.size());
            return (FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(
                    fromIndex, toIndex)));
        }
    };

    progress.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    task.setOnSucceeded(ev -> {
        table.setItems(task.getValue());
        table.setPlaceholder(oldPlaceHolder);
    });
    new Thread(task).start();

    return new BorderPane(table);
}
```

Comment: Curiosity question. Since the OP is getting the data from a database or a server: Is it a preferred way to use the ObservableList on the server or should you stick with a java.util.List there?

Comment: Most servers run in headless environment, so you will get a `List` in most cases from the Server side which you can wrap and return as `FXCollections.observableList(list)`.

Comment: @PeterPenzov What do you mean with "upgrade"?

Comment: How I can hide the pagination bar when the content of the table is empty?

Comment: Please ask a new question for this. Or figure it out by yourself, hint: Bind the visibility of the pagination to an empty binding with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html

Comment: One more question: do you know how I can disable table animation when I switch pages?

Comment: I can not see a property for that, so I fear you will have to write a custom `Skin` for this.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the table into a StackPane and on top of it you put a progress indicator.

Here's an example:

```
public class TableWithProgressIndicator extends Application {

    private final static int dataSize = 10_023;
    private final static int rowsPerPage = 1000;

    private ObservableList<Sample> dataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new ArrayList<Sample>(rowsPerPage));
    private TableView<Sample> table = null;


    StackPane tablePane = new StackPane();
    ProgressIndicator progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();

    private List<Sample> loadData(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {

        List<Sample> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try {

            for (int i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; i++) {
                list.add(new Sample(i, "foo " + i, "bar " + i));
            }

            Thread.sleep(2000);

        } catch( Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }


    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {

        table = createTable( dataList);

        Pagination pagination = new Pagination((dataSize / rowsPerPage + 1), 0);
        progressIndicator.setMaxSize(200, 200);

        // wrap table and progress indicator into a stackpane, progress indicator is on top of table
        tablePane.getChildren().add(table);
        tablePane.getChildren().add(progressIndicator);

        pagination.setPageFactory(new Callback<Integer, Node>() {

            public Node call(final Integer pageIndex) {

                progressIndicator.setVisible(true);

                dataList.clear();

                // long running background task
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {

                        try {

                            int fromIndex = pageIndex * rowsPerPage;
                            int toIndex = Math.min(fromIndex + rowsPerPage, dataSize);

                            List<Sample> loadedList = loadData(fromIndex, toIndex);

                            Platform.runLater(() -> dataList.setAll( loadedList));

                        } finally {

                            Platform.runLater(() -> progressIndicator.setVisible(false));

                        }
                    }
                }.start();

                return tablePane;
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(pagination), 1024, 768);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Table pager");
        stage.show();
    }

    private TableView<Sample> createTable( ObservableList<Sample> data) {

        TableView<Sample> table = new TableView<>();

        TableColumn<Sample, Integer> column1 = new TableColumn<>("Id");
        column1.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().id);
        column1.setPrefWidth(150);

        TableColumn<Sample, String> column2 = new TableColumn<>("Foo");
        column2.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().foo);
        column2.setPrefWidth(250);

        TableColumn<Sample, String> column3 = new TableColumn<>("Bar");
        column3.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().bar);
        column3.setPrefWidth(250);

        table.getColumns().addAll(column1, column2, column3);

        table.setItems( data);

        table.setPlaceholder(new Label(""));

        return table;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class Sample {

        private final ObservableValue<Integer> id;
        private final SimpleStringProperty foo;
        private final SimpleStringProperty bar;

        private Sample(int id, String foo, String bar) {
            this.id = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(id);
            this.foo = new SimpleStringProperty(foo);
            this.bar = new SimpleStringProperty(bar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Instead of a default `Thread` and countless `Platform.runLater(...)` calls, use a `Task`. It was written by JavaFX developers for a reason..

Comment: The answer is simple: The Oracle documentation isn't good enough. I simply didn't know about that, neither about the Placeholder usage of which I don't know if it's intended for the progress indicator or if it's abuse of it. The setOnSucceeded looked suspicious, I had to read up if it's on the FX thread or not. And besides of that, what happens on a cancel? On the one hand you get setOnFinished methods, on the other for the Task you have setOnCancelled and setOnThisAndThat. imo a setOnFinished is missing. My solution is valid, but your solution is the preferred one, of course.

Comment: Not good enough? I admit, there are some JavaFX APIs which are badly or even not documented, but `Task` is not one of them and on top of that there are many good tutorials on JavaFX Multithreading. But you are right that my solution may have edge cases (in case of an error), but SO is not here for writing someone others code, just to point in the right direction ;-)

Comment: I meant the documentation of the usage. Otherwise the question of the OP wouldn't have been necessary. If JavaFX wants to be a competition to HTML5, then I'd expect client-server-communication examples. But you can neither find them in the TableView, TreeView, TreeTableView examples, nor in the Pagination example. I hope that changes.